# Instantiate a new instance of ValueConverter for each ListBox item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

I have defined the following enum to represent a bitfield in my program:

```
[Flags]
public enum CXIOByte
{
    None = 0,
    Bit0 = 1,
    Bit1 = 2,
    Bit2 = 4,
    Bit3 = 8,
    Bit4 = 16,
    Bit5 = 32,
    Bit6 = 64,
    Bit7 = 128
}
```

At runtime I create a list of instances of type CXIOByte (encapsulated in a class where the CXIOByte instance is named Value) and they are represented in my XAML as a set of checkboxes:

```
ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding InputItems}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="models:CXInputOutputModel">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource enumBitfieldValueConverterI}, ConverterParameter={x:Static models:CXIOByte.Bit0}}" Margin="5"/>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource enumBitfieldValueConverterI}, ConverterParameter={x:Static models:CXIOByte.Bit1}}" Margin="5"/>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource enumBitfieldValueConverterI}, ConverterParameter={x:Static models:CXIOByte.Bit2}}" Margin="5"/>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource enumBitfieldValueConverterI}, ConverterParameter={x:Static models:CXIOByte.Bit3}}" Margin="5"/>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource enumBitfieldValueConverterI}, ConverterParameter={x:Static models:CXIOByte.Bit4}}" Margin="5"/>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource enumBitfieldValueConverterI}, ConverterParameter={x:Static models:CXIOByte.Bit5}}" Margin="5"/>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource enumBitfieldValueConverterI}, ConverterParameter={x:Static models:CXIOByte.Bit6}}" Margin="5"/>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource enumBitfieldValueConverterI}, ConverterParameter={x:Static models:CXIOByte.Bit7}}" Margin="5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I have an IValueConverter that helps to evaluate the 'checked' status of an individual bit in the field:

```
public class EnumBitfieldValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private int targetValue;

    public EnumBitfieldValueConverter()
    {
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int mask = (int)parameter;
        targetValue = (int)value;

        return ((mask & targetValue) != 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        targetValue ^= (int)parameter;
        return Enum.Parse(targetType, targetValue.ToString());

    }
}
```

An instance of this IValueConverter keeps track of the runtime value using an internal 'targetValue' property.

Now, this works fine for a single InputItem in the ListView.  But if I have more than one InputItem in the ListView I require each item to use its own instance of the IValueConverter.  Otherwise each item interfers with the targetValue of a previous item.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Create the value converter as a resource in `<DataTemplate.Resources>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare converter as non-shared Resource:

```
<local:EnumBitfieldValueConverter x:Key="enumBitfieldValueConverterI" x:Shared="False">
```

`{StaticResource}` will return new instance each time

Comment: I need to look into this so that I can gain a better understanding.  But your answer is confirmed as working.
When I began to type x:... I didn't get "Shared" as an intellisense option.  I only got "FieldModifier", "Key", "Name" and "Uid".  However, typing it in regardless was still accepted by the compiler.